# Salesforce Bulk Rest Api doesn't support JSON content type

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to insert data into slaesforce using bulk rest api. For this I am first creating a new Job using :-
    https://instance_name—api.salesforce.com/services/async/APIversion/job
And then for adding a batch to job I am using :-
    https://instance_name—api.salesforce.com/services/async/APIversion/job/jobid/batch

But while making these api calls using curl, it only supports XML content_type. Is there any restriction of content_type while using bulk rest api? If I change content_type to JSON it throws error "

> {"exceptionCode":"UnsupportedContentType","exceptionMessage":"JSON
>   content type is not supported"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is supported from Spring '16 onwards. It should work if your API version is newer than that.

Guide for API v38.0:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_preparing.htm